# Update [can check if the date is future ]

Tags: sql

hi guy I need to know in SQL can check is the date is future and display future date

If can may I know how to work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can find a lot of answer with 30 seconds search in Google. Next time, please use it first. Also read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN SSMS, you can do

```
select distinct name from mytable
```

The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values.

You can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `distinct` as below

```
select distinct name
from tablename
```

Because `distinct` remove duplicates from returning rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the distinct keyword

```
select distinct name from tablename;
```

A distinct keyword is used to display only the unique (distinct) entry in the column, hence all the duplicate entries will not be displayed in your query output.[detailed tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm)